# Is there some method in the Java standard library to get the smallest enum out of a set of enums?

Tags: java, collections, enums, compare, max

Consider a collection consisting of enum types. Is there some library method `min` (or `max`) which accepts this collection (or varargs) and returns the smallest/highest value?

EDIT: I meant the natural order of enums, as defined by their `compare` implementation of `Comparable`.

Comment: Do you min value with the small ordinal?

Comment: How do you define "smallest"? Does your enum use a Comparator?

Comment: @soc, what kind of order do you think of when you say smallest/highest?  1) Natural ordering is the order in which the constants are declared? 2) Alphabetical order of the constants?

Comment: public enum Planet {MERCURY, [...], EARTH} What is the smallest enum to you? If the smallest makes sense to you, you should consider adding a field to your enum. Your program should not rely on the order your enums are declared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums implement `Comparable<E>` (where `E is Enum<E>`) and their natural order is the order in which the enum constants are declared.
You can use their default Comparable implementation to get the max and min constants as declared:

```
public enum BigCountries {
    USA(312), INDIA(1210), CHINA(1330), BRAZIL (190);

    private int population;

    private BigCountries(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

}
```

Then you can use:

```
BigCountries first = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(BigCountries.values())); // USA
BigCountries last = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(BigCountries.values()));  //BRAZIL
```

Probably, a faster way would be to use direct access to the array returned by the `values()` method:

```
BigCountries[] values = BigCountries.values();
System.out.println(values[0]); // USA;
System.out.println(values[values.length-1]); // BRAZIL;
```

Note that the parameter given to the enum has no effect in the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some `Set<MyEnum>`, it should already be of type `EnumSet`. Sadly, this class does not provide `first` and `last` methods, but it does guarantee to iterate in increasing order, so you can reliably use, for example, the first and last elements in `thatSet.toArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want custom ordering (say alphabetical), use a custom comparator on any collection

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyEnumType>
{
    public int compare(MyEnumType enum1, MyEnumType enum2)
    {
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o1.toString());
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the declared order, put them into a SortedSet

```
SortedSet<MyEnumType> set = new TreeSet<MyEnumType>();
set.add(enum1);
```